# Convert Easting/Northing to Lat/Long in FME

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, fme-transformer

I would like to convert a series of points from Easting/Northing to Lat/Long. So far I have tried using the Coordinate System Extractor and Coordinate System Setter but these dont seem to offer what I am after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the **Reprojector transformer**, then set in the transformer's properties "**Source Coordinate Systems**" as your original coordinate system and the "**Destination Coordinate System**" should be set to "**LL84**". I assume that you are using a point geometry FeatureType.

[image]